# Automatically starting the Remote desktop sessions when computer boots up

Tags: boot, remote-desktop, thin-client

I have a HP Thin Client PC, which is connected to VMware ESXI host with two virtual machines. The thin client connects to the virtual machines through Remote Desktop. I would like the thin client to start the remote desktop to start automatically when it boots up. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: What OS is the Thin Client running? If Windows, is it an Embedded version?  Are they frozen?

Comment: It is Windows Embedded..@techie007 does that affect anything?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you start a remote desktop connection (assuming you're using the windows remote desktop tool) you'll be able to expand the screen.
From there you're able to save the connection settings (including credentials etc), save this .rdp file on the desktop.

Next drag the file into start>programs>startup.

Done!